# Uploading files larger than allowed in servers POST settings

Tags: php, uploading

I'm creating a site in which user can upload his docs. 
Settings on server:

```
upload_max_filesize 2M
post_max_size 2M
```

The FTP uploading is unlimited.

Is there a way to allow the user upload larger files via FORM?

Comment: No. form uploads are limited to HTTP. you'd need a client-side Flash or Java app to do FTP, or just provide an `ftp://` url for the user and let them finagle out how to get their browser to do an upload.

Comment: @MarcB Thanks... That's not gon'na work for them, I know theese users +)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try by ini_set function to set the php values for upload_max_filesize at runtime.
but that won't work because the variable is not setted in time so that it can really ovverride the php.ini directives.

So, if you can't access the apache conf, you can try to set this kind of things in the .htaccess

I'd also suggest to set the post_max_size that could help a lot.

```
php_value upload_max_filesize 32M
php_value post_max_size 32M
```

Comment: The php docs specifically rule out ini_set() as a possibility. Don't try that. The rest will work, however.

Comment: yay, I know that's y I suggested the .htaccess

Comment: Really? _"You could try by ini_set function to set the php values"_ ... in any case, +1 for improving on my answer with the addition of `post_max_size`

Answer (score 2):

If you don't have access to edit php.ini, you can use your .htaccess file:

```
php_value upload_max_filesize 10M
```

According to http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.list.php:

> Entry can be set in php.ini, .htaccess or httpd.conf

It's worth noting that as always, if you edit your php.ini or apache httpd.conf you'll need to restart apache before you see the changes reflected in your web environment.

Answer (score 2):

POST is HTTP, and so are forms.  HTTP is not FTP.

Unless you install some sort of FTP UI plugin (or Java/Flash app), or simply expose the FTP to the users, you're not going to be able to circumvent this.

Answer (score 1):

If you really need a way and cannot change upload_max_filesize, let your users split the file up into parts below 2M. You can join them on the server. 
Maybe you could show the users a list of the uploaded parts. Whenever the user uploaded all parts, he clicks "All parts uploaded" and then the server joins them.

Comment: Haha how many end users do you know who would say, "Sure, let me just use my handy RAR file-splitter and I'll upload this thing in 7 parts." ???

Comment: If they don't know how to split files, a short step by step guide would help them. If you know an easier way (or any other way) to upload files above max_upload_filesize, please tell us.

Comment: Not knocking you, I'm despairing over the capabilities of the average end user :)

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no other way than editing exactly those two `php.ini` settings.

Comment: There is no way _in php_ ... though there are other ways, as noted in the php docs.

Comment: Yep, you say to change that settings values.